# How to set SharePoint2010 feature IsHidden property in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

How to set SharePoint2010 feature IsHidden property in VS 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can double click on your Feature in VS.NET 2010 and open up a feature designer. Check the property window at this time and you can set many Feature specific properties including IsHidden.

[image]

Comment: Cool,I have overlooked this properties window.I thought it would be configurable in the Feature editor itself.But it is all good now.Thanks again.